# Birt report Line printer support

Tags: birt

I need to print the output of Birt report to a line printer (Tally T6045 Printer) 
in Text mode.
Please help...

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing... i use BIRT and need to generate a report for POINT of SALE printers (text only), and i don't want to implement crazy workarounds like converting PDF to TEXT :-\

Answer (score 1):

I would look at extending the emitter API to put out a format that would likely render nicely on a line printer.  I looked and did n see one already in the community.

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportEngineAPI.php

http://www.birt-exchange.com/be/documentation/BIRT_220/EngineJavadoc/engine/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/emitter/package-summary.html